# Disabling a AWS API from a regional endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I need to find a way to disable an API that is on a regional/edge-optimized endpoint.

I know for private APIs you can add a recourse policy that disables it like this

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}"
    }]
}
```

However it does not work on regional.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why it wouldn't work on Region? It normally works. Did you re-deploy your stage after changes to API policy?

Comment: I literally just did it again and re-deployed and it worked, no clue why it didnt work before

Comment: Sometimes it takes a minute or two to take an effect. Anyway, if you don't mind I can provide an answer for future referene.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

API gateway resource policies **do work for regional APIs**. However, after changing the policy, once must **re-deploy the stage** for the policies to take effect.

Also, it takes **few moments** for the policies to take an effect. The policies do not apply immediately after deployment.